# How to make a request with an operator or/and at the same time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in ruby , my code is following

```
      class DepensesController < ApplicationController
       before_action :set_depense, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] 


       # GET /depenses
       # GET /depenses.json

    def index

        @structure = Structure.all
        @structure.each do |structure|

         #request 1 for each structure spend
       @show_depense = Depense.where(structure_id: structure.id)
         end

     #request  2 for categories
     @groupes =   Groupe.all.select { |m| m.parent_id == nil || m.parent_id =="" }

    end
end
```

[Here is an illustrative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5V8o.png)

My first request allows me to display the expense to perform by the structure in which I am and the all goes well

My second displays all categories of expenses and each expense is in a category.

My problem is that the categories created in other structures display in my home what I want to avoid ... my intension is to display only what my structure to create as category and expense

From query 1 I thought the combined with query 2 to have the categories created by the structure in which the logged in user is.
I have the following query:

```
    @groups = Group.all.select ((| m | m.parent_id == nil || m.parent_id   == "") AND (structure_id: structure.id))
```

It does not work, and I do not know how to go about it

I specify that the **id of category and structure are in foreign key in the table expense**

could you help me? thank you in advance

Comment: By using `Structure.all.each` you are performing a loop for all of the Structures in your database. You should select only one Structure with `Structure.find(params[:structure_id])` or `current_user.structure` if your use Devise and your User has only one structure. 
If you have several Structure, only the last Depense will be saved in `@show_depense` since you are changing its value at each iteration.
You should use `Groupe.where(parent_id: ['', nil])` instead of `Groupe.all.select { |m| m.parent_id == nil || m.parent_id =="" }`

Comment: Thank you your request **(Groupe.where(parent_id: ['', nil])**  allowed me to solve in part my problem